# How to bind dropdownlist to List of Type <Model> using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've come to various examples, but I don't think I can find what I'm exactly looking for.

I have a model that contains a class:

```
public class StateResources
{
  public List<States> statesList { get; set;}
}

public partial class States
{
    public int? StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

I have code which can execute to get data from a database which populates the statesList. I call that in my controller so I can display it in my view.

```
public ActionResult StatesView(List<States> listofStates)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     try
     {
         StatesResources stateResource = new StatesResources();
         stateResource.ReturnStateResources(); // Assume there is a method in 
                                               // my States Resource Class 
                                               // that executes code to 
                                               // retrieve data from a db.
                                               // and turns it into a list.

         listOfStates = stateResource.statesList;
         return(listOfStates);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // catches exception if exists
     }
  }
  else
  {
    //throws error if ModelState.IsValid == false.
  }

     return View("StatesView");
}
```

In my view:

```
@model List<States>

   <body>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID) @*This is where I'm having trouble*@
   </body>
```

I don't know how to get the model to that drop down list. I believe the issue lies where it must be a select list item, but I'm not quite sure because I've seen DDL's that do not use them from some examples I've seen. I know there are several examples of how to pass data into a DDL, but I don't think I've come across an example similar to mine on how it's being retrieved from a db and making it a list of a specific class type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confused by your controller code because it looks like a POST and a GET together since you are passing a list to the controller action method and you've got a ModelState.IsValid call.

You don't need to return your custom type to your view.  The easiest would be for you to populate SelectListItem directly from your data provider.

ViewModel

```
public class StatesEditViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int SelectedState { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
}
```

controller actions

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StatesEdit()
    {
        StatesResources stateResource = new StatesResources();
        stateResource.ReturnStateResources(); // Assume there is a method in 
                                              // my States Resource Class 
                                              // that executes code to 
                                              // retrieve data from a db.
                                              // and turns it into a list.

        var model = new StatesEditViewModel { States = stateResource.statesList.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.StateName, Value = s.StateID }).ToList() };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StatesEdit(StatesEditViewModel editModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //repopulate your state list
            StatesResources stateResource = new StatesResources();
            stateResource.ReturnStateResources(); // Assume there is a method in 
                                                  // my States Resource Class 
                                                  // that executes code to 
                                                  // retrieve data from a db.
                                                  // and turns it into a list.

            var model = new StatesEditViewModel { States = stateResource.statesList.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.StateName, Value = s.StateID }).ToList() };
            return View(model);
        }

        //Save your selected sate to somewhere
        //redirect back to your GET action
        return RedirectToAction("StatesEdit");
    }
```

and finally your view

```
@model StatesEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h2>title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("StatesEdit", "<controller where you define you actions>", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedState, Model.States)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can bind DropDownListFor With Model. Using this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, new SelectList(Model.statesList ,"StateID", "StateName"))

public class StateResources
    {
        public List<States> statesList { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
    }
```

In your view:

```
@model StateResources
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult StatesView(StateResources model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     try
     {
         StatesResources stateResource = new StatesResources();
         stateResource.ReturnStateResources(); // Assume there is a method in 
                                               // my States Resource Class 
                                               // that executes code to 
                                               // retrieve data from a db.
                                               // and turns it into a list.

         model.statesList = stateResource.statesList;         
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // catches exception if exists
     }
  }
  else
  {
    //throws error if ModelState.IsValid == false.
  }

     return View("StatesView", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In View

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("TypeDropDown", Model.TypeSelectList, new { onclick = "Type_OnChange()" })%>
```

In View Model.

```
public SelectList TypeSelectList;

public void loaddata
{
 TypeSelectList = GetOptions();
}
```